# Unable to upload image to Firebase Cloud Storage from Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

From my application I select an image(read and write to storage permissions has been granted) then I get a bitmap from the URI I receive from the `onActivityResult`. After that I set an ImageView with the bitmap `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`. I then proceeded to convert  the bitmap to an array of bytes

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int quality){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
```

Afterwards I tried uploading the bytes to Firebase Cloud Storage

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images/users/image.jpg");
        
           UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putBytes(bytes);

            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Task<Uri> downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                    downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            //...
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
                    }
                }
            });
```

I get the same error: An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.

My firebase dependencies:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
```

I have changed the dependencies again and again and again, the firebase realtime database functionalities are working but I am stuck with this problem.

Another dependency I tried `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'`

Comment: Please don't use all-caps as that is considered yelling, and leads to more downvotes and less chance of people actually helping.

Comment: Done thanyou. What do you think I can do about my problem?